# how does the alghorithm Exclusive Feature Bundling work in lightgbm?cound anyone give me an example

Tags: lightgbm

[enter link description here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6907-lightgbm-a-highly-efficient-gradient-boosting-decision-tree.pdf)

Exclusive Feature Bundling